# Google Play Saved Games conflicts show wrong snapshots

Tags: android, conflict, google-play-games

i use different savegames in my app. "coins" , "levels" , ...

It works fine but if a conflict detected then its wrong result.

```
/**
     * Conflict resolution for when Snapshots are opened.  Must be run in an AsyncTask or in a
     * background thread,
     */
    Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult processSnapshotOpenResult(Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result, int retryCount) {

        retryCount++;

        int status = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "Load Result for saveGame<" + savedGame.getName() + "> status: " + status);

        if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            return result;
        } else if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONTENTS_UNAVAILABLE) {
            return result;
        } else if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_CONFLICT) {

            saveResolveConflictGameData = true;

            Log.i(TAG, "Konflikt aufgetreten");
            Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult resolveResult = null;
            Snapshot snapshot = result.getSnapshot();
            Snapshot conflictSnapshot = result.getConflictingSnapshot();

            Snapshot mResolvedSnapshot = null;
            mResolvedSnapshot = snapshot;


            SnapshotMetadata s1Meta = snapshot.getMetadata();
            SnapshotMetadata cMeta = conflictSnapshot.getMetadata();

            // resolveConflict and get new merged Parser Object
            //
            Parser conflictParserTemp = savedGame.resolveConflict(snapshot, conflictSnapshot);

            if ( conflictParserTemp == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "savedGame.resolveConflict(snapshot,conflictSnapshot) Error");
                return  result;
            }

            //
            // wurde schon ein conflict behandelt ?
            //
            if ( conflictParser != null ) {
                // merge previous Conflict with this conflict
                conflictParser.merge(conflictParserTemp);
            } else {
                // set first conflict Parser
                conflictParser = conflictParserTemp;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict() Step %d", retryCount));

            resolveResult =
            Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict(
                    activity.mGoogleApiClient, result.getConflictId(), mResolvedSnapshot).await();

            if (retryCount < MAX_SNAPSHOT_RESOLVE_RETRIES) {
                // Recursively attempt again
                return processSnapshotOpenResult(resolveResult, retryCount);
            } else {

                // Failed, log error and show Toast to the user
                String message = "Could not resolve snapshot conflicts";
                Log.e(TAG, message);
                Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return resolveResult;
            }

        }

        // Fail, return null.
        return null;
    }
```

The Error is that if I load savegame "coins" I become all conflicts from other savegames.

I see it here.

```
SnapshotMetadata s1Meta = snapshot.getMetadata();
            SnapshotMetadata cMeta = conflictSnapshot.getMetadata();
```

The Snapshot for korrekt coins savegame show this:

> SnapshotMetadataEntity{Game=GameEntity{ApplicationId=520840013521,
>   DisplayName=Crush me, PrimaryCategory=Simulation,
>   SecondaryCategory=null, Description=hallo, DeveloperName=steffen
>   höhmann, IconImageUri=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null,
>   HiResImageUrl=null, FeaturedImageUri=null, FeaturedImageUrl=null,
>   PlayEnabledGame=true, InstanceInstalled=true,
>   InstancePackageName=cherry.de.wubbleburst, AchievementTotalCount=0,
>   LeaderboardCount=0, RealTimeMultiplayerEnabled=false,
>   TurnBasedMultiplayerEnabled=false, AreSnapshotsEnabled=true,
>   ThemeColor=00456B, HasGamepadSupport=false},
>   Owner=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=113260033482974102226,
>   DisplayName=shoehmi, HasDebugAccess=false, IconImageUri=null,
>   IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null, HiResImageUrl=null,
>   RetrievedTimestamp=1454003980807, Title=Anfänger,
>   LevelInfo=com.google.android.gms.games.PlayerLevelInfo@1e1b36},
>   SnapshotId=drive://113260033482974102226/520840013521/coins,
>   CoverImageUri=null, CoverImageUrl=null, CoverImageAspectRatio=0.0,
>   Description=null, LastModifiedTimestamp=1454004003382, PlayedTime=-1,
>   UniqueName=coins, ChangePending=true, ProgressValue=-1}
>   drive://113260033482974102226/520840013521/coins

and the snapshotData:

> timestamp;coins#1453929273252;100#1453929280956;-70#230179;70

but he shows me savegame snaphot from "level" savegame as conflicted Snapshot:

> levelId;points#1;3241#2;9634

and the Conflict Snapshot Metadata say it is a "coins" savegame:

> SnapshotMetadataEntity{Game=GameEntity{ApplicationId=520840013521,
>   DisplayName=Crush me, PrimaryCategory=Simulation,
>   SecondaryCategory=null, Description=hallo, DeveloperName=steffen
>   höhmann, IconImageUri=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null,
>   HiResImageUrl=null, FeaturedImageUri=null, FeaturedImageUrl=null,
>   PlayEnabledGame=true, InstanceInstalled=true,
>   InstancePackageName=cherry.de.wubbleburst, AchievementTotalCount=0,
>   LeaderboardCount=0, RealTimeMultiplayerEnabled=false,
>   TurnBasedMultiplayerEnabled=false, AreSnapshotsEnabled=true,
>   ThemeColor=00456B, HasGamepadSupport=false},
>   Owner=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=113260033482974102226,
>   DisplayName=shoehmi, HasDebugAccess=false, IconImageUri=null,
>   IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null, HiResImageUrl=null,
>   RetrievedTimestamp=1454003980807, Title=Anfänger,
>   LevelInfo=com.google.android.gms.games.PlayerLevelInfo@1e1b36},
>   SnapshotId=drive://113260033482974102226/520840013521/coins,
>   CoverImageUri=null, CoverImageUrl=null, CoverImageAspectRatio=0.0,
>   Description=null, LastModifiedTimestamp=1454004003382, PlayedTime=-1,
>   UniqueName=coins, ChangePending=true, ProgressValue=-1}
>   drive://113260033482974102226/520840013521/coins

Why only if conflict occured and without conflicts its running correct and 
save / load correct??

Please Help me???

sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Have you checked the [Handling saved game conflicts](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames?hl=en#handling_saved_game_conflicts) in the Games API documentation? Its a bit different in your case since the example it gave is for multiple device saves, but it may help you a bit in finding out a possible solution to your case.

Comment: Thx, but this is not the problem. my code is a little modified code from the API. I handle only my saved data bevor I resolve the conflict.  The resolve process is the same.